# Is there a list of css attributes that are not allowed in pdf rendering in Salesforce?

Tags: visualforce, force.com

I've been looking around the web and do not see that this question has been asked or answered anywhere, hoping someone can help. Is there a published list of css attributes that are not allowed in pdf rendering in Salesforce?

Answer (score 3):

The Render Engine used by Salesforce to render PDFs only supports CSS 2.1 along with a couple of special CSS commands specific to the render engine itself, so you would not want to use any CSS 3 attributes. The CSS 2.1 specification can be found [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/#minitoc).